# CWAC-MediaRouter overwrites my app theme

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have an android app that I'm trying to use CWAC-MediaRouter lib for, and whenever I import it, then my app's theme gets reset back to a plain black and white theme and I'm not sure exactly why.  Since the app isn't using gradle, I'll explain my process for importing:

So my initial project structure is basically like this:

```
Project Root
    |---MyApp -> Depends on mediarouter, appcompat
    |---|---src
    |---|---res
    |---android v7 mediarouter module -> depends on appcompat
    |---android v7 appcomp module
```

When I build at this point, my app looks as expect.  The correct background, action bar color, etc.

Now I want to import CWAC-MediaRouter as a module so I can add the cast button.

I go to Project Structure, then hit the + and Import Module.  I browse to the folder where I cloned the repo, and then select the mediarouter folder.  I'm presented with this screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1pwb.png

When I hit next and finish the import wizard, I then set up my dependencies, and now my project structure looks like this:

```
Project Root
    |---MyApp -> Depends on mediarouter, appcompat, cwac-mediarouter
    |---|---src
    |---|---res
    |---android v7 mediarouter module -> depends on appcompat
    |---android v7 appcomp module
    |---cwac-mediarouter module -> depends on appcompat, mediarouter
```

Now at this point, whenever I build and run the app, my entire app has lost it's theme.  White background, black action bar, etc etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this one out, and thought I would share in case anyone else runs into a problem like this.

My app only had themes defined for up to v11.  Then when I imported cwac-mediarouter, it has theme files for up to v14.  So when I used my v19 device to run the app,  (for some reason that I still can't really explain), it started reading the v14 styles.xml from cwac-mediarouter.

To fix it, all I did was create a values-v14 directory in my app and copy the stylesheet from v11 into it.  All works as expected now.

Comment: This is my fault. I apparently left the style resources in there from when the project was generated. I will get this cleaned up shortly. My apologies for the error, and thanks for pointing this out!